# Multiple XMLHttpRequest in one page

Tags: javascript, php

I have a situation where I am making the following requests and for some reason only one of them is working?

The expected result is that the second div which is populated by filter2 will bring in the necessary information, however this is not working even though this is following the same logic as filter 1?

The code for the actual requests is here:

Request 1:

```
function show1(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { 
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "filter1.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

Request 2:

```
function show2(str) {
            if (str == "") {
                document.getElementById("id2").innerHTML = "";
                return;
            }
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else { 
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("id2").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "filter2.php?p=" + str, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
```

The php code is as follows for both of the requests is as follows:

Filter1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<?php
include('db.php');

$q = strval($_GET['q']);

mysqli_select_db($mysqli,"database");
$search="SELECT * FROM column WHERE type = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$search);

echo "<ul id=\"list\">";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<li>";
echo "<a class=\"class\">" . $row['column'] . "</a>";
echo "<a class=\"class\"><strong>" . $row['column'] . "</strong></a>";
echo "<button><img src=\"icons/image.png\" style=\"height:42px;width:42px;\" onclick=\"show2(this.value)\" value=\"" . $row['column'] . "\" class=\"class\"></button>";
echo "</li>";       
}
echo "</ul>";
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Filter2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<?php
include('db.php');

$p = strval($_GET['p']);

mysqli_select_db($mysqli,"database");
$search="SELECT * FROM column WHERE name = '".$p."'";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$search);

echo "<table>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<tr id=\"id\"><td><strong>" . $row['column'] . "</strong></td></tr>";
echo "<tr id=\"id\"><td><a href=\"tel:"  . $row['column'] . "\">TestContact</a></td></tr>";
echo "<tr id=\"id\"><td>" . $row['column'] . "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr id=\"id\"><td><a href="  . $row['column'] . "\">Website ></a></td></tr>"; 
}
echo "</ul>";
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not sure if this is a common mistake or I have some kind of clash/stupid syntax error, but this is driving me crazy and I would be forever grateful for anyone to help?

Comment: img tag don't have value property the attribute will not work. If you want to add value use `data-value="xxx"` attribute and `this.dataset.value` ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: the response would be the entire page which would not be valid when injected by the ajax callback

Comment: I'm not seeing a call to `show2t` anywhere in the code you posted. And HTML you insert into an existing document shouldn't contain the full structure, just the `<div>` or `<ul>`.

Comment: @ChrisG I seem to have made a slight error, the call to show2 is part of the first filter (basically the button click in filter 1 triggers the second filter showing the result of show2). The code above is now correct

Comment: Ok, so when you click the button, do you see the XHR in the browser console? Or are you getting errors?

Comment: Regarding XHR, I get an undefined output? - http://www.website.com/filter2.php?p=undefined

Comment: an `img` element does not have a `value` attribute. You could add a `dataset` attribute instead and use that value

Comment: forgive my shortsightedness - how/where is `show1` invoked?

Comment: So far I see: 1). xmlhttp will be global variable, so if requests made simultaneously, second handler will overwrite previous one. It would be better to declare “var xmlhttp;” in the beginning if each show functions. 2). Each filter parameter need sql escape before injected into query

Comment: @RamRaider it's invoked through another button, same process as show2 and it works perfectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in a comment ( and was also stated in the 1st comment by @jcubic ) an `img` element doesn't have a value attribute which is, I suspect, the reason your function is passing `undefined`

Instead you can use a `dataset` attribute and alter the parameter passed to the inline function / event handler:

```
echo "<button><img src=\"icons/image.png\" style=\"height:42px;width:42px;\" onclick=\"show2(event)\" data-value=\"" . $row['column'] . "\" class=\"class\"></button>";
```

and the javascript function

```
/* passing event allows access to event.target amongst other things - this is useful */

function show2( e ){
    var el=e.target;
    var str=el.dataset.value;
    if( str )/* etc */
}
```

that said you'd be much better creating a generic ajax function ( or better yet look into the `fetch` api ) and write wrapper functions for each use case.